# Using DISTINCT in a joined subquery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Here is the fiddle for this question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0569eb/1

I have a table for comments, with replies stored in the same table as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `posted_by` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX (`parent`),
  INDEX (`posted_by`),
  INDEX (`sort`)
  
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `comments` (`id`, `parent`, `posted_by`, `comment`, `sort`) VALUES
  ('1', '0', '1', 'Here is a comment by user 1', '5'),
  ('2', '1', '2', 'Here is a reply by user 2', '5'),
  ('3', '1', '3', 'Here is a reply by user 3', '5'),
  ('4', '1', '2', 'Here is a reply by user 2', '5'),
  ('5', '0', '2', 'Here is a comment by user 2', '2'),
  ('6', '0', '5', 'Here is a comment by user 5', '3');
```

I need to be able to select main comments that are posted by a user, or have a reply posted by that same user. The following is what I came up with to get the appropriate data for user 2.

Since there can be multiple replies on a single comment, I am using DISTINCT in a subquery to only get one reply per row. Is this an appropriate solution, or is there a better way to approach this situation?

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.comment
FROM comments c
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT comments.parent FROM comments WHERE comments.posted_by = 2) r ON r.parent = c.id
WHERE 
  (
    c.posted_by = 2
    OR r.parent IS NOT NULL
  )
  AND c.parent=0
ORDER BY c.sort DESC;
```

The following is the expected output for comments relating to user 2

[image]

Comment: Group by without aggregating is the same as a select distinct. PS Please research before considering posting a question. If you want to optimize, learn & apply basics & report findings, this shows no research. Especially read basics of indexing. PS Index default order is ascending.

Comment: Hi, can you post what your expected output rows would be from the data you have supplied.

Comment: @MarkB For sure! Updated my question.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS [mre] PS When there are no duplicates rows, x join y where c or d is x join y where c union x join y where d. You can google re that. (Learn about googling with 'site:'.) PS Generally there is no "best" in engineering, measure in your circumstances. PS Research?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you mean by "this situation". This particular code? What part? Code that is like this in the sense that ...?

Comment: The distinct replacing the group was to go in the outermost select.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: to remove the need for sort in the result as suggested in the comments

Nothing wrong with your solution, it works and is as concise as it can be.

As an alternative (but not better) you could use a UNION

```
SELECT id, comment 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        c.id, 
        c.comment,
        c.sort
    FROM comments c
    WHERE posted_by = 2 AND parent = 0
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.id, 
        c.comment,
        c.sort
    FROM comments c
        JOIN comments p ON p.parent = c.id 
    WHERE p.posted_by = 2) x
ORDER BY sort DESC;
```

Comment: I haven't looked to see whether the question query or its modified version or your should be left joining anywhere. But I'm pretty they should be.

Comment: The second SELECT in the UNION is only for rows with parents, so the join is an INNER JOIN